# Scala regex extract domain from urls

Tags: regex, scala

I want to extract bell.com from these following input using Scala regex. I have tried a few variations without success.

```
"www.bell.com"
"bell.com"
"http://www.bell.com"
"https://www.bell.com"
"https://bell.com/about"
"https://www.bell.com?token=123"
```

This is my code but not working.

```
val pattern = """(?:([http|https]://)?)(?:(www\.)?)([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+)[/]?(?:.*)""".r
url match {
  case pattern(domain) =>
    print(domain)
  case _ => print("not found!")
}
```

EDIT:
My regex is wrong. Thanks to @Tabo. This is correct one.

```
(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+)/?.*
```

Comment: How will you handle subdomains? Your problem may be intractable.

Comment: Don't try to regex this.  Let a URL parser handle it.

Comment: @jcdyer Can you please provide an example so I can approve your answer?

Comment: @jcdyer I found this. https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/scala-uri Is this what you mean?

Comment: @angelokh: Sorry.  I hadn't been on SO in a while.  Looks like you got an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
import java.net.URL
import util.Try

val t = "https://www.bell.com?token=123"

val url = Try { new URL(t) }.toOption
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use Java URL class to get Host, or you can check Apache library

```
new URL("https://www.bell.com?token=123").getHost
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the `java.net.URL`method, but...

For future reference, you have a couple of issues in your regex. Square brackets match character sets so `[http|https]` is the same as `[htps|]` (meaning 'h', 't', 'p', 's', or '|'). I think you mean `http|https` or simply `https?`.

Also, if you are only trying to match *just* the domain, you want to only have one capturing group. Note that `(?:blah)` denotes a non-capturing group, while `(blah)` is a capturing group. The three capturing groups in your regex are `([http|https]://)`, `(www\.)?`, and `([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+)`. You really only want the last one.

Try:

```
(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+)/?.*
```

Test it here - https://regex101.com/r/xW4iY7/2